# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException when Accessing a Variable in Java

Tags: java

```
package model;

import model.interfaces.DicePair;
import model.interfaces.Player;


public class SimplePlayer implements Player{

private String playerName;
private int points;
private String playerId;
private int bet;
DicePair dicePair;


public SimplePlayer(String playerId,String playerName,int points){
    this.playerId=playerId;
    this.playerName=playerName;
    this.points=points;

}

public String getPlayerName(){
    return playerName;
}

public  void setPlayerName(String playerName){
    this.playerName=playerName;
}

public  int getPoints(){
    return points;
}

public void setPoints(int points){
    this.points=points;
}

public  String getPlayerId(){
    return playerId;
}

public  boolean placeBet(int bet){

    if(bet>getPoints()){

        return false;

    }
    else{
        this.bet=bet;

    return true;}

}

public  int getBet(){
    return bet;
}

public  DicePair getRollResult(){
    return dicePair;


}

public  void setRollResult(DicePair rollResult){
    this.dicePair=rollResult;
}

public  String toString(){
    return "Player: id="+playerId+", name="+playerName+", points="+points;
}
```

}
// this class have the points value

```
    package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import model.interfaces.DicePair;
import model.interfaces.GameEngine;
import model.interfaces.GameEngineCallback;
import model.interfaces.Player;


public  class GameEngineImpl implements GameEngine {
SimplePlayer simplePlayer;
    public static int NUM_FACES = 6;
    Collection<Player> players= new ArrayList<Player>();
GameEngineCallback gameEngineCallback;
DicePair dicePair;
DicePair dicePair2;
Player player;
public void rollPlayer(Player player, int initialDelay,
        int finalDelay, int delayIncrement){


    for(int i= initialDelay; i<=finalDelay;i+=delayIncrement){
        int dice1=(int)(Math.random()*NUM_FACES+1);
        int dice2=(int)(Math.random()*NUM_FACES+1);
        DicePairImpl dicePairImpl=new DicePairImpl(dice1,dice2);
        gameEngineCallback.intermediateResult(player,dicePairImpl,this);


        try {
            Thread.sleep(initialDelay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    int dice1=(int)(Math.random()*NUM_FACES+1);
    int dice2=(int)(Math.random()*NUM_FACES+1);
    DicePairImpl dicePairImpl=new DicePairImpl(dice1,dice2);
    gameEngineCallback.result(player,dicePairImpl,this);
    player.setRollResult(dicePairImpl);
    dicePair=dicePairImpl;
};
    public void addPlayer(Player player){
    players.add(player);

};

public boolean removePlayer(Player player){
    if(players.contains(player)==true){
        players.remove(player);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

};
public void calculateResult(){
.....
int points=simplePlayer.getPoints();// get error from here which is Exception      in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
System.out.println(points);
}
}
```

In this class, for the method calculateResult(), i need to get the points value for player. i tried to write int points=simplePlayer.getPoints(); i keep causing error, which i am lost and cannot get the points value.

**The error is as follows:**

> Exception      in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class SimplePlayer implements Player{

private String playerName;
private int points;
private String playerId;
private int bet;
DicePair dicePair;


public SimplePlayer(String playerId,String playerName,int points){
    this.playerId=playerId;
    this.playerName=playerName;
    this.points=points;

}
```

// this is the simplePlayer class

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You still haven't posted the full error stack. Usually the error stack shows line numbers. Take a screenshot of it erroring out

Comment: int points=simplePlayer.getPoints(); it keep cause error for this line, i didn't provide my full code for GameEngineImpl, so if i post the full error stack, you cannot find that line.

Comment: please let me if that fixed it, if not please post the code in between the declaration and usage and we can go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error is because `simplePlayer` is null. You probably didn't initialize `simplePlayer` using its constructor. Please post the code between the declaration and the usage if you wish for me to confirm. To use the constructor, you should probably use:

```
simplePlayer = new SimplePlayer( 1, "Adam", 0 );
```

You can further test it by executing the following line before the `simplePlayer.getPoints()` call.

```
if( simplePlayer == null )
    System.out.println( "simplePlayer is null!" );

int points=simplePlayer.getPoints();
```

**EDIT:**
After looking through the code, the OP found that `this.simplePlayer=simplePlayer` solve the issue to not make it null.

Comment: yes, i got the message which is"simplePlayer is null", in the test class, there is simplePlayer= new simplePlayer(1, "player1",1000), so what should i do???

Comment: well it means `simplePlayer` is null. You need to post the code in between for me to see why `simplePlayer` is null as nothing you posted indicates it's being set to null.

Comment: I think i kind of fix the problem, i put a this.simplePlayer=simplePlayer, and then i get the points value.

Comment: @Jason6666 Awesome! I don't suppose you could accept my answer for point out that it was null in the first place? :D